# How to get caml query to return list items created by the current user?

Tags: client-object-model, caml-query, caml

I want a caml query that only retrieves items created by the user currently logged in. I tried this

```
specifier = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value></Eq>";
camlquerystring = "<View><Query><Where>" + specifier + "</Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>";
```

However I am not getting any items. I should be getting a lot of items...

Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AssignedTo should be replaced with Author and you should then see all your items.

Comment: I tried that, but I am still getting 0 items back.

Comment: Nevermind, this worked, I just had another issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Integer'>" + _id + @"</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
```

where _id is user's ID.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler CAML - items created by current user

```
query.Query = @"<Where>
                  <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Author' />
                    <Value Type='User'><UserID/></Value>
                  </Eq>
                </Where>";
```